# How add publish config block to a custom entity content

Tags: 8, entities

i have a custom entity content : Product.
I am looking for a way to give the posibility to change the url of the product like this block :

[image]

Block on the right.

It's a screen of article content.

Here my annotation for my entity content :

```
/**
 * Defines the Produits entity.
 *
 * @ingroup boutique
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "produits_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("Produits"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\boutique\ProduitsEntityListBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\boutique\Entity\ProduitsEntityViewsData",
 *
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\boutique\Form\ProduitsEntityForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\boutique\Form\ProduitsEntityForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\boutique\Form\ProduitsEntityForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\boutique\Form\ProduitsEntityDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "access" = "Drupal\boutique\ProduitsEntityAccessControlHandler",
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\boutique\ProduitsEntityHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *   },
 *   base_table = "produits_entity",
 *   admin_permission = "administer produits entities",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "name",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "uid" = "user_id",
 *     "langcode" = "langcode",
 *     "status" = "status",
 *   },
 *
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/produits/{produits_entity}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/boutique/produits/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/boutique/produits/{produits_entity}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/boutique/produits/{produits_entity}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/boutique/produits/liste",
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "produits_entity.settings"
 * )
 */
```

Is there a way for extend my entity content to the node properties ?

Comment: Do you want an option to "publish" or "unpublish" your entity content in your custom content entity - product?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/2655780. It will not give you the vertical tabs, that is not specific but a setting to add a url alias field to any content entity.

Comment: Or you can define it as a field yourself, like pathauto_entity_base_field_info() does for node.

Comment: i want just the possibility for the user or path auto to change the path. I ll check your link Berdir thx

Comment: i think the better way is to create a custom field for the path... i ll try to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have solve my problem (don't work with pathauto):

I create a custom field in my form for the path :

[image]

And in my submit :

i use the

> $path =
>   \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save($system_path, $path_alias, $langcode);

```
 public function save(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $entity = $this->entity;
    $status = parent::save($form, $form_state);


    switch ($status) {
      case SAVED_NEW:
        drupal_set_message($this->t('Created the %label Produits.', [
          '%label' => $entity->label(),
        ]));

        $path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save('/produits/'.$entity->id(), $form_state->getValue('path')[0]['value'], 'fr');

        break;

      default:
        drupal_set_message($this->t('Saved the %label Produits.', [
          '%label' => $entity->label(),
        ]));
    }
    $form_state->setRedirect('entity.produits_entity.canonical', ['produits_entity' => $entity->id()]);
  }
```

Now i need to work with the service path.alias_storage when user modify and delete my product.

Comment: Don't forget that drupal is open source and you can always look how the feature is implemented in the node entity.